# Adding a layer of abstraction to UserFrom - am I doing it right?

Tags: excel, vba, variables, initialization, userform

I'd like to create a UserForm showing a progress of some operation (let's call it ProgressForm). I'd also like to make this form simple to reuse in multiple Workbooks by me and other coworkers. Finally, I'd like to make my ProgressForm as fool-proof as possible.

To make my form simple to use I've decided to create 3 "methods":

P_Begin(Goal) - to set up a goal and prepare form

P_Step() - to record a progress and update form

P_End() - to dispose a form

Now, to make it fool-proof I need some "system" that prevents using P_Step or P_End before P_Begin is called (as we need to set our goal FIRST before we try to make any progress).

My idea is to use a flag (let's call it "IsCreated") that will tell whether or not P_Begin was called. Here's what I've got so far:

```
Private IsCreated As Boolean
Private Goal As UInteger
Private Progress As UInteger

Function P_Begin(pGoal As UInteger)
    If IsCreated Then
        Err.Raise 5
    End If

    Goal = pGoal
    Progress = 0
    IsCreated = True

    ' Prepare ProgressForm elements here

    Me.Show vbModeless
End Function

Function P_Step()
    If Not IsCreated Then
        Err.Raise 5
    End If

    Progress = Progress + 1

    ' Update ProgressForm elements here
End Function

Function P_End()
    If Not IsCreated Then
        Err.Raise 5
    End If

    IsCreated = False

    Me.Hide
End Function
```

This is how I imagine sample use:

```
Sub DoingSomething()
    ProgressForm.P_Begin pGoal:=100
    For i = 1 To 100
        ' Doing Something
        ProgressForm.P_Step
    Next i
    ProgressForm.P_End

    ProgressForm.P_Begin pGoal:=200
    For i = 1 To 200
        'Doing Something Else
        ProgressForm.P_Step
    Next i
    ProgressForm.P_End

    ' and so on...
End Sub
```

Looks pretty nice, right? Well, there's a "little" problem: IsCreated variable is not initialized when P_Begin is first called so my code is unreliable. I have some ideas how to deal with it, but none of them satisfies me:

1. Making IsCreated Public and setting it to False in Workbook_Open Sub - I don't like it as it makes ProgressForm less simple to use - Form user would have to remember to set IsCreated to False in every workbook that uses ProgressForm. Also: abstraction.
2. Dropping fool-proof requirement by not using IsCreated flag at all.
3. Rely on a fact that uninitialized Boolean is by default set to False, so IsCreated is conveniently set to False by default - it's just wrong, very, very wrong.
4. Somehow pushing IsCreated initialization to `ProgressForm_Initialize()` method. However, in order to show my form I first need to call P_Begin to set a goal. But P_Begin relies on IsCreated variable... Oops, circular dependency.
5. Somehow wrapping ProgressForm in class? It's just my guess, I must admit: I don't know how OOP works in VBA.
6. Somehow counting ProgressForms and setting IsCreated to false in the first one? Sounds a bit messy. Once again: it's just my wild guess based on [this post](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=90416), which I don't understand entirely...

Usually when I encounter a problem with apparently no solution, it usually means that my idea is fundamentally incorrect. Maybe there is better, VBA-way to achieve desired results?

Comment: Declaring `IsCreated` as Boolean will automatically assign it a default value of `False` - that seems OK to me.

Comment: @TimWilliams Yeah, but it solves my problem only "by accident". Isn't it some kind of a "bad habit" or "dirty trick"? Especially because I can't find anything about default value of Boolean in VBA documentation. Boolean Data Type: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264308%28v=office.14%29.aspx nothing. Data Type Summary: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251528%28v=office.14%29.aspx nope.

Comment: It's not "by accident" if you're relying on the language spec to assign a default value.  "When you run a macro, all the variables are initialized to a value. A numeric variable is initialized to zero, a variable length string is initialized to a zero-length string (""), and a fixed length string is filled with the ASCII code 0. Variant variables are initialized to Empty. An Empty variable is represented by a zero in a numeric context and a zero-length string ("") in a string context."  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/843144

Comment: And - http://www.jpsoftwaretech.com/vba/default-values-variables/

Comment: @TimWilliams I'm sorry Tim, but I can not completely agree with you. First, the text you quoted states that "A numeric variable is initialized to zero", but nowhere is Boolean classified as numeric variable. Secondly, I don't believe [this test](http://www.jpsoftwaretech.com/vba/default-values-variables/) is conclusive: just because someone, somewhere, using particular machine, particular OS version and particular VBA version received False from uninitialized Boolean variable doesn't proves that False is in fact default Boolean value.

Comment: @TimWilliams However, you've inspired me to dig deeper into a subject and this is what I found: According to [this MSDN doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wts33hb3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) "The default value of Boolean is False." for Visual Basic for VS2010. Furthermore [this MSDN doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa192490%28v=office.11%29.aspx) describing differences between VB and VBA **does not** points out any differences on how variable's default values are treated. So I think it's safe to assume that in fact, False is default value of Boolean data type for VBA =)

Answer (score 0):

Change as follows (possible solution):

```
Private IsCreated As Integer
...
IsCreated = 99 ' in P_Begin
...
If (IsCreated <> 99) then ' raise error
...
IsCreated = 0  ' in P_End
```

This relies on the fact that VB will [probably] never initialize an integer variable to 99.